# How to get size of Java tooltip

Tags: java, tooltip

I have a Component where getToolTipText(MouseEvent) returns some HTML so it's nicely formatted (including showing multiple lines). However I want to place the tooltip (by overriding getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent)) to try to make sure it isn't over certain parts of the window, and to do that I need to know the dimensions the tooltip will have. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.swing.JToolTip` inherits `getPreferredSize()` from `javax.swing.JComponent` so you can do something like:

```
Dimension d = myToolTip.getPreferredSize();
```

And use `Dimension d` in your `getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent)`

Comment: Thanks David. To help out anyone else encountering this, the full solution was to override Component.createToolTip and keep a copy of the JToolTip object created, then in getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent) to call getToolTipText(MouseEvent) and enter the return value in to JToolTip.setTipText(String), then call JToolTip.getPreferredSize(). Without the call to JToolTip.setTipText the preferred size was the size of whatever previous tooltip was displayed!

Comment: Ah, a further update, it appears it doesn't need to be the JToolTip returned by Component.createToolTip, simply creating a JToolTop and calling setTipText works fine.