# How to Resize a Text Tool Tip in JAVA swing

Tags: java, swing, resize, tooltip

I am working on a small project in which I want let the user know some information in entering data using tool tips, but the text tool tip size is too small, not the best view of that, so i was wondering if someone can help me out with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to resize your tooltip, you can probably call `setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize)`. You can set the dimension like so:

```
Dimension d = myToolTip.getPreferredSize();
// Or:
Dimension d2 = new Dimension(20, 30);
myToolTip.setPreferredSize(d2);
```

EDIT: If you want to adjust the font of the text of the tooltip you can do so like this:

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.font", new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension)) for the javadoc, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-awt-dimension-class/) for an example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040827/how-to-get-size-of-java-tooltip) for another SO question, and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/customize-the-tooltip-font-color-background-and-foreground-color-in-java) for JToolTip customization.

Comment: Ok i'll check if it works or not. thankyou for your reply

Comment: also @MehrozMustafa see the edit and if this worked for you consider accepting the answer ;)

Comment: DIdnt worked sadly but still upvoted the answers, hoping for an easy solution